# Regular expression matches everything except "/"

Tags: python, regex

Forgive me if this is a terribly simple question. It's been a while since I've written regular expressions.  Your help to brush of the rust is most appreciated. I am using regex in python

I am trying to parse through some URLs. Here are the typical format of the URLS I am parsing:

```
https://www.anysite.com/word/123456789/description-of-the-page
https://www.anysite.com/word/123456789/description-of-the-page/someword
https://www.anysite.com/word/123456789/description-of-the-page/thisword
https://www.anysite.com/word/123456789/description-of-the-page/anyword
```

I would like to write an expression that will only match the first URL and not the last three. That is, I want a regular expression that will only match if there is not a "/" following the "/" following the numeric string "123456789".

Ignoring the main URL, I have tried a negative lookahead assertion without success:

```
/word\/.+?\/(?!\/).+/
```

This matches all of four examples.

I can't be specific as to not ending in "/someword" "/thisword" or "/anyword" as I do not have a complete list of these words.

Thanks again for looking and your thoughts!

Comment: `[^\/]*` should do it. Don't forget to use the dotall parameter.

Comment: This gets close.  It gets me everything before that last "/". I need it to not match if there is a "/"

Comment: have you considered running your URL through `urlparse` before trying to parse with regex?  You're going to save yourself some headaches.

Comment: Why on earth are you using a regex here? Purposeful obfuscation?

Comment: I have my reasons. muahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that as:

`^https?:\/\/[^\d]*(\d+)\/[^\/]*$`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/aC8aJ7

Comment: Very helpful!  I ended up going with:      \/projects\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*$  I needed to make this change because it is possible that where I have written 123456789 there could be alpha characters too. But for the example above,  you are spot on!  Thanks much!

Comment: I will in 3 minutes when the system allows me

Answer (score 0):

How  about:

```
/word\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+/
```